# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row because add foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm facing error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ( `` `report_sales`.`subdistributor`, CONSTRAINT `subdistributor_id_dso_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_dso`) REFERENCES `dso` (`id_dso`) ``) (SQL: `` insert into `subdistributor` (`id_subdist`, `id_kategori_subdist`, `id_dso`, `nama_subdist`, `alamat1_subdist`, `alamat2_subdist`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (SUBDIST001, SUPERINDI, DSO-ACEH, PT Sumber Cipta Multiniaga, Jln . Gedong123, Samping gang, 1, 2021-10-25 09:52:37, 2021-10-25 09:52:37) ``)

This happen because I add foreign key on my migrate table, I need foreign key to relate to another table.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSubdistributor extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subdistributor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id_subdist');
            $table->string('nama_subdist');
            $table->string('alamat1_subdist')->nullable();
            $table->string('alamat2_subdist')->nullable();
            $table->string('id_kategori_subdist');
            $table->string('id_dso');
            $table->foreign('id_dso')->references('id_dso')->on('dso');
            $table->string('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('created_date',$precision = 0);
            $table->string('modified_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('modified_date',$precision = 0)->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary('id_subdist');
        });
    }
```

controller

```
public function import_excel(Request $request) 
    {
        // validasi
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
        ]);
 
        // menangkap file excel
        $file = $request->file('file');
 
        // membuat nama file unik
        $nama_file = rand().$file->getClientOriginalName();
 
        // upload ke folder file_subdistributor di dalam folder public
        $file->move('file_subdistributor',$nama_file);
 
        // import data
        Excel::import(new SubdistributorImport, public_path('/file_subdistributor/'.$nama_file));
 
        // notifikasi dengan session
        Session::flash('sukses','Data Subdistributor Berhasil Diimport!');
 
        // alihkan halaman kembali
        return redirect('/subdistributor');
    }
```

I'm try to solved myself but still did't found how to solved this.
Please anyone can help me?
I'm using laravel 8 and my database is mysql

Comment: The query citated in the error message is synthactically wrong - string literals are not enclosed with the quote chars.

Comment: Please make sure string are enclodes like 'SUBDIST001', clean up tables and see.

Comment: @Akina that's most likely an artefact of the way Laravel formats the errors. It would use placeholders for the actual query but when dumping the error it will replace them with the values used but I think it doesn't quote them in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have existing data in your tables which doesn´t match the foreign key?
Make sure that both columns (`subdistributor`.`id_dso` and `dso`.`id_dso`) has the same datatype and length.

Make sure, that all data, also "DSO-ACEH" exists in `dso`.`id_dso` column you wish to relate to.